# Deploying Blazor to local IIS Express - Error: Duplicate ScriptResourceHandler

Tags: c#, blazor, iis-express

I need to deploy a blazor web application to computers that need to run our web app completely disconnected from the Internet running under IIS Express and working with a local database installed on the client machine. I know it sounds peculiar, but please stick with me...

The blazor app that we're trying to run locally and disconnected from the Internet normally runs on an Intranet web server and connects to our main production SQL Server. So we cannot customize the web app for MAUI. We want to be able to drop our unmodified blazor app right inside IIS express and it detects that it's being run from the C:\FSAPublish folder and connects to the local SQL Express database instead of the remote production SQL Server, then the data is synchronized back to the production server when they return to the office with an Intranet connection available. Again, I've tried this self-hosting of my blazor app inside IIS Express is working just fine on my dev machine, so I know it can be done. I'm receiving errors on new machines that I try to deploy it to. There's just some missing piece on the brand new machines that I'm trying to set up. In other words, we want to write our blazor app once but deploy it into two different scenarios (connected with remote SQL Server and disconnected with local SQL Server Express on client machine).

Our blazor application targets the .NET 6 Framework.

Deploying and running my blazor application on my development works great using IIS Express (NOT inside visual studio, but actually launched using a batch file containing "start iisexpress /path:C:\FSAPublish"). However, upon deploying to any brand new client workstation with the .NET 6 runtime and IIS Express installed, it fails upon pulling up the edge browser and trying to open URL http://localhost:8080/blank (which works great on my dev machine).

I'm not sure why the error is mentioning a duplicate scriptResourceHandler in my web.config file, when I don't even have that in my bare bones blazor web.config file (shown below the error).

Any help would be appreciated.

Error message:

> If you see the text "There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined", this error is because you are running a .NET Framework 3.5-based application in .NET Framework 4. If you are running WebMatrix, to resolve this problem, go to the Settings node to set the .NET Framework version to ".NET 2". You can also remove the extra sections from the web.config file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" 
                 resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\FSAWeb.Server.dll" 
           stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
           stdoutLogFile=".\logs\\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: web.config file got clobbered above. Here it is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">

<system.webServer>

<handlers>

<add name="aspNetCore" path="\\\\\\\*" verb="\\\\\\\*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />

</handlers>

<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\\\\\\\\FSAWeb.Server.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\\\\\\\\logs\\\\\\\\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />

</system.webServer>

</location>

</configuration>

Comment: You must edit the question to include new information. Nobody is happy to read ugly formatted contents in comments.

Comment: OK, so no matter what I do the stackoverflow post editor is removing all of my web.config contents except for the empty <system.webServer>. Even if I properly mark it as code by indenting it or surrounding it with "...". Also, as far as the comments, it always removes the CR/LF from the comments so it scrambles it up there. In any event, it's only about 12 lines long and doesn't contain any scriptResourceHandler tags.

Comment: OK, my latest edits to the post now are properly showing my bare-bones web.config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have resolved this issue. Turns out that on my Dev box (where it runs properly), I had a different version of IIS Express that Visual Studio had installed, and that version had an extra folder called "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\ASP.NET Core Module" with lots of entries in the AppServer\applicationhost.config file referencing assemblies in that folder.
The plain-vanilla version of IIS Express available for download (that I had installed on the new client computer that wasn't working) didn't have this sub-folder nor config file entries. I uninstalled IIS Express and installed Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition with only ASP.NET Web development selected, and it installed it's custom version of IIS Express with the folder and then self-hosting works. However, I obviously can't ask everyone to install VS 2022 Community Edition, so I'll have to figure out how to wrap a MAUI application somehow around my existing Blazor application without disrupting my ability to still deploy my Blazor application as a normal web server application.

Comment: To get Blazor running on ISS you'll need to install the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0

Comment: That isn't enough to get IIS Express hosting working with a Blazor app. It doesn't have the ASP.NET Core Module included. This problem has been resolved.